# Subscribing to the built-in topic "DCPSTopic" in DDS

Tags: c#, data-distribution-service

I am trying to create the simplest C# application that will allow me to get the topics currently available in the selected DDS domain. But I can't seem to make it work.

```
// Create the DDS Domain participant on domain ID 0
DDS.DomainParticipant participant =                          
             DDS.DomainParticipantFactory.get_instance().create_participant(
                    0,
                    DDS.DomainParticipantFactory.PARTICIPANT_QOS_DEFAULT,
                    null, /* Listener */
                    DDS.StatusMask.STATUS_MASK_NONE);
DDS.Subscriber sub = participant.get_builtin_subscriber();
DDS.DataReader reader1 = sub.lookup_datareader("DCPSTopic");
DDS.TopicBuiltinTopicDataDataReader builtinReader1 =  
                       (DDS.TopicBuiltinTopicDataDataReader)reader1;
DDS.TopicBuiltinTopicDataSeq topicSeq = new DDS.TopicBuiltinTopicDataSeq(10) ;
DDS.SampleInfoSeq infoSeq = new DDS.SampleInfoSeq(10);
builtinReader1.read(topicSeq, 
                    infoSeq, 
                    10, 
                    DDS.SampleStateKind.ANY_SAMPLE_STATE, 
                    DDS.ViewStateKind.ANY_VIEW_STATE,
                    DDS.InstanceStateKind.ANY_INSTANCE_STATE);
```

When running the code above, I get a "Retcode_NoData" exception in the last line (builtinReader1.read(...)) even though both publishers and subscribers are running and posting in the same domain (domain 0). Do you have any idea about what could be wrong with my code?

By the way. I use RTI Connext 5.0 implementation of DDS.

Regards
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With RTI Connext, the `TopicBuiltinTopic` does not behave as one might expect. Check out the documentation of the [C# API DDS::TopicBuiltinTopicData Class Reference](http://community.rti.com/rti-doc/500/ndds.5.0.0/doc/html/api_dotnet/classDDS_1_1TopicBuiltinTopicData.html):

> Note: The `DDS_TopicBuiltinTopicData` built-in topic is meant to convey
>   information about discovered Topics. This Topic's samples are not
>   propagated in a separate packet on the wire. Instead, the data is sent
>   as part of the information carried by other built-in topics
>   (`DDS::PublicationBuiltinTopicData` and
>   `DDS::SubscriptionBuiltinTopicData`). Therefore `TopicBuiltinTopicData`
>   DataReaders will not receive any data.

What it basically says: because of the way discovery is implemented in Connext, you will not see any data in any `TopicBuiltinTopicData` DataReaders. This is what you observe in your code snippet.

Fortunately, it is still possible to get information about Topics on the bus. This has to happen via the PublicationBuiltinTopicData and SubscriptionBuiltinTopicData. If you look at the documentation of the [C# API DDS::PublicationBuiltinTopicData Class Reference](http://community.rti.com/rti-doc/500/ndds.5.0.0/doc/html/api_dotnet/classDDS_1_1PublicationBuiltinTopicData.html#), you can see that the data contains the string fields `topic_name` and `type_name`. Additionally, you can get information about the structure of the type, but that is more advanced and implementation specific.

---

Three remarks in case you plan to implement the reading of the Publication and Subscription builtin Topics. First, in stead of hardcoding the name of the built-in Topic, like you did with `"DCPSTopic"`, it is better to refer to the corresponding TypeSupport attribute, as in:

```
reader = sub.lookup_datareader(
             DDS.PublicationBuiltinTopicDataTypeSupport.PUBLICATION_TOPIC_NAME);
```

Then it is good to know that with Connext, built-in DataReaders will not contain any samples about Publications or Subscriptions that live in the same DomainParticipant as the built-in Subscriber. In other words, you can only see other Participant's Entities, but not your own.

Finally, while playing around with you code, I noticed that the reading of the samples did not work unless I replaced the constructor invocations of the sequences as follows:

```
DDS.SampleInfoSeq infoSeq = new DDS.SampleInfoSeq();
```

in stead of

```
DDS.SampleInfoSeq infoSeq = new DDS.SampleInfoSeq(10);
```

and similar for the data-sequence. I do not know why that is, but it should not have any practical implications.

Comment: Hi Reinier, Thanks for your feedback! I have implemented your 3 suggestions and are also using Subscription and Publication builtin topics/datareader now. But my application still does not give any feedback (except for the "Retcode_NoData" exception). I am running the application on a laptop where other of DDS applications is running, all on domain 0, but they do not show up in my application.             Have you got any other suggestion to what could be wrong?  Thanks again! John

Comment: Do you see anything when running the `rtiddsspy` tool on your laptop? It should discover all DataReaders and DataWriters on the bus and print their Topics, and all updates (by defult). If that does show no results, then there is something wrong with the setup of your laptop. If it does show results, could you please check out this [code snippet](http://pastebin.com/awEHZTBv) and see if that works for you? In order to debug this, I would start off with your laptop only and run the snippet in combination with, for example, RTI's Shapes demo.

Comment: I tried running your codesnippet instead of mine and your worked just as it was supposed to :) The builtin TopicReader does not give any results, but it is possible (as you said) to read the topics from publishers/Subscribers. Thank you, very much, for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Rainier is right. Connext DDS does not propagate the Topics directly in the `TopicBuiltinTopicData`; rather it does it indirectly in the `PublicationBuitinTopicData` and `SubscriptionBuiltinTopicData`. This is permitted by the DDS Specification.

There is information on how to use the builtin Topics in this HOWTO titled [Detect the presence of DomainParticipants, DataWriters and DataReaders in the DDS Domain](http://community.rti.com/content/forum-topic/detect-presence-domainparticipants-datawriters-and-datareaders-dds-domain). The HOWTO includes some working example code. It is in Java instead of C# but it should be easy to map. The example there reads one Sample at a time so you do not need to deal with the sequence sytax.

The reason why you must use:

```
DDS.SampleInfoSeq infoSeq = new DDS.SampleInfoSeq();
```

Instead of:

```
DDS.SampleInfoSeq infoSeq = new DDS.SampleInfoSeq(10);
```

Is that the read/take APIs that have two different behaviors depending on whether the passed sequences are "empty" (i.e. have a zero allocated/maximum length) or have an allocated length.

If the sequence is empty, which is what you get with the default constructor, then read/take behave as zero-copy API's. This means that the actual elements in the sequence are "loaned" from the ones already stored inside the middleware. For this reason the sequence that must be passed in has to be an "empty" sequence so that the middleware knows it is OK to replace the contents with references to the internal elements. After accessing the elements you must return the 'loaned elements' back to the middleware calling the `DataReader::return_loan` operation.

If the sequences are not empty. Then DDS will assume the elements are pre-allocated and will try to copy the data into the elements you passed.  The problem with the code you showed is that

```
DDS.SampleInfoSeq infoSeq = new DDS.SampleInfoSeq(10);
```

Allocates just the sequence itself. But not the elements. So the read/take call will fail when it tries to make the copy. If you wanted to use this non zero-copy API you have to follow the call with the allocation/assignment of each element, that is:

```
for (int i=0; i< 10; i++ ) {
    infoSeq.set_at(i, new DDS.SampleInfo());
}
```

And the same would apply for the data sequence as well.
If you do this you would not have to use the `DataReader::return_loan` operation. But there would be extra copies so it is less efficient.

You can find more information on how to use DDS Sequences in this HOWTO titled [Howto use OMG DDS Sequences in C++](http://community.rti.com/content/forum-topic/howto-use-omg-dds-sequences-c-rti-connext-dds). It is written with C++ examples but the principles apply to all the languages.

Regards,
Gerardo